# How to make ui.Panel elements transparent (Earth Engine)

Tags: google-earth-engine

I would like to be able to adjust the transparency of the Earth Engine `ui.Panel` element. The [documentation for panel style](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#ui.panel.style) has no apparent option to set opacity/transparency; is there any way to do this?

Here is a panel example:

```js
var panel = ui.Panel({
  style: {
    height: '235px',
    width: '600px',
    position: 'bottom-right',
  }
});

Map.add(panel);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the CSS `rgba(red, green, blue, alpha)` function as a value for the `backgroundColor` style property (can be applied to `ui.Label` as well):

```js
var panel = ui.Panel({
  style: {
    height: '235px',
    width: '600px',
    position: 'bottom-right',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)',
  }
});

Map.add(panel);
```

[image]